# Kettle / Pentaho Data Integration not usable: very slow to start up and hangs on right click

Tags: macos, pentaho, kettle

For all practical purposes, I cannot work with Kettle / Data Integration, although it is half of my new job. Does anyone have any insights?

#### Issue:

Kettle is very slow to launch, and immediately hangs and needs to be Force Quit when I right click on anything in the left side panel.

That is the main issue, as there are some things you can only do by right clicking on the object you want in the view panel. But I believe there is also a configuration issue. For example, when I try to create a new database connection after creating a new transformation (both from the File menu), I get this error:
“org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException”

#### My config:

Mac OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra)
Kettle, also known as Pentaho Data Integration, version 7.1.0

#### What I already attempted:

- Uninstall and reinstall Kettle in 2 ways:
  o From the installer package on this website (which redirects to https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/7.1/pdi-ce-7.1.0.0-12.zip/download) 
  Uninstall: move Data Integration folder to Trash, as well as all files and folders containing “Kettle", and then Empty Trash 
  o From Homebrew in the Terminal, using: `brew install kettle` 
  This way installs version 6 
  Uninstall: `brew uninstall --force kettle`
- Close all apps in use, hard reboot my computer, kill memory intensive processes in Activity Monitor
- `Sudo purge`

#### Notes:

Kettle takes over 1 GB of memory right away after being started. 
Here is how I launch it, in Terminal, not by clicking on the .app item, because that doesn't work:

- When installed from installer dmg package : `/Applications/data-integration/Data\ Integration.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub`
- When installed from homebrew: `spoon.sh`

Answer (score 0):

For all's information, I got an answer that did the trick here:

https://community.hds.com/message/37078-re-kettle-data-integration-is-very-slow-to-start-up-and-immediately-hangs-after-right-click-on-anything-in-the-left-view-panel?commentID=37078#comment-37078

Answer (score 0):

you have to rise the ram , open the spoon.sh an modify proper section about memory